# Issue to show products that realted to category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm

I'm facing an issue to show only the products that realted to  category , (it shows all the products that exists

**the conroller:**

```
class SortController extends MainController{
 public function sortByASC( $category_url,Request $request){
   $sort = $request->get('sort', 'asc');
   if ($category=Categorie::where('url','=', $category_url)){
    $products = Product::orderBy('price', $sort)->get();
    return view('content.sort')->with('products', $products) ;
}
}
```

**view:**

```
form id="order-product-form" method="get" action=">>{{url('shop/{category_url}/sort=ASC')}}"enctype="multipart/form-data">     
@if ($products)   
@foreach($products as $product)
{{ $product['title']}}
```

**MODEL:**

```
class Product extends Model {
    static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data){
        $data['products']=$data['category']=[];
        if ($category=Categorie::where('url','=', $category_url)->first()){
         $category= $category->toArray();
         $data['category']=$category;
         $data['title']=$data['title']. ' | ' . $category['title'];
         if ($products=Categorie::find( $category['id'])->products){
            $data['products']= $products->toArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your data structure/migrations

Comment: how can I show it?

Comment: You should have files detailing how to create your database structure in `database/migrations` if you've done it this way. Otherwise, you can show the table structure if the relevant tables. The method for getting the table structure can vary depending on which database (MySQL etc.) you're using and whatever software you're using (phpMyAdmin etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `->first()` at your controller category condition query